# speed up delete duplicates command on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a table t1 like this:

```
id     |   abstract_text |
1      | long paragraph1 |
2      | long paragraph2 |
3      | long paragraph1 |
```

It has around 150,000 unique id's, but some id's have the same abstract_text value (like 1 and 3).

I'm using this command

```
delete t1 from t1 
inner join t1 t2 
where
    t1.application_id < t2.application_id AND
    t1.abstract_text=t2.abstract_text;
```

However, it's been over 2 hours and it hasn't finished running. The abstract_texts are long paragraphs, so I know it won't be fast. I tried creating an index but I'm not sure how to use that as I can't create a index with the abstract_text b/c it's too long (throws `ER_TOO_LONG_KEY: Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes` error).

Any ways to speed up this process?

Comment: Not really, since you have long texts to match that cannot be fully indexed and therefore probably partially stored in overflow pages in the table space, not just in the data page.

Comment: If two abstracts share the same first 250 characters, are they likely to be duplicates?

Comment: I suggest create a new table (e.g. t1_new) then insert only the data you want into it. Do checking and once you're satisfied, rename t1 to t1_old and t1_new to t1. At least if the new table doesn't have the data you want, you still can refer back to the old table.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes. Even the first 100 characters I'd say they are likely duplicates.

Comment: So note that you can create indexes on the first n characters of a column https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Comment: @Strawberry unfortunately my column is fulltext, and the docs seem to say that I can't do that for fulltext columns. Know any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Delete manipulation is a costly process for databases, you can prefer creating a new table in which the duplicate paragraphs are removed in such a way that

```
CREATE TABLE t3 AS
SELECT t1.application_id, t1.abstract_text
  FROM t1 
  JOIN t1 t2
 WHERE t1.application_id > t2.application_id 
   AND t1.abstract_text=t2.abstract_text
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(application_id) AS application_id, abstract_text
  FROM t1 
 GROUP BY abstract_text
 HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ec9f7e944eaaddfcbc4a28a66031d2d)</kbd>